# Unity 4.6 assets not getting applied in Windows 8.1 export

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-8.1

I am building a game in which I need to change its theme at runtime according to player's choice. Here is a chunk of code to change background image:

```
    string path;
    string themeName;
    themeName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Theme_Name");

    //Change Background Image
    path = "Assets/Textures/" + themeName + "/Background.jpg";
    Background_Image.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>(path);
```

This works perfectly in Unity however no image gets applied to the background when I export the game for Windows 8.1. The variable 'path' evaluates to "Assets/Textures/Default/Background.jpg" which is the right path and works for Unity project but not Windows.

Do I need to separately export my images folder or use a different path after exporting game or something? Might be a very stupid thing but I am kinda lost here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Resources.Load** instead. **Resources.LoadAssetAtPath** works only in the Editor.

Create a folder called "Resources" under the "Assets" folder. Move all your images to this folder.

Then change your code to the below

```
 path = themeName + "/Background.jpg";
 Background_Image.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path);
```

The above code assumes that you have a subfolder named with your themes inside the Resources folder.

For example, if one of your themes is called "Theme1", then the background Image should be stored in {Your_Project_Folder}/Assets/Resources/Theme1/Background.jpg

Comment: Thankyou for explaining. Works perfectly both with unity and VS :)

Comment: One more thing though, what is the use of LoadAssetAtPath if we can achieve same with just load?

Comment: According to Unity's docs "This is useful for quickly accessing an asset for use in the editor only." I've personally never seen much use of it.